# Asirit - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows a tenth?

### ?עשירית - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 0.1.

Lazy gematria may be worthy of discission, but perhaps not of a full-fledged answer. [This may not apply in the conventional sense, but, *e.g.*, saying x is a quarter of y is just not keeping in the spirit. However, there maybe be examples that the Arizal, Baal Haturim, etc., mention and they are perfect for comments.]

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous three hundred fifty entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Answer (score 1):

You shall set aside every year a tenth part of all the yield of your sowing that is brought from the field. [Devarim 14:22]

Answer (score 1):

This stone which I have set [as] a monument will become a House of God and of all that You give, I will surely give a tenth to You. [Genesis 28:22]

Answer (score 0):

And [Abram] gave him a tenth of everything. [Genesis 14:20]

Answer (score 0):

The omer is a tenth of an ephah. [Exodus 16:36]

Answer (score 0):

He will take a tenth part of your grain and vintage and give it to his eunuchs and courtiers. [1 Samuel 8:15]

Answer (score 0):

The amount of charity one should give is as follows: if one can but afford, let him give as much as is needed. Under ordinary circumstances, a fifth of one's property is most laudable. To give one-tenth is the average disposition. But to give less than one-tenth is niggardly. When the Rabbis said a "fifth" they meant a fifth of the property the first year only and a fifth of the profits in succeeding years. [Shulchan Arukh, Yoreh De'ah 249:1]